# Same UUID being generated in multi-threaded application

Tags: java, multithreading, uuid

I am using the UUID.randomUUID().toString() to append a unique value to a string that is ultimately stored in the database and has unique constraint on it

But because my application is multi-threaded the execution happens at the same time of UUID generation and ultimately the same UUID is appended to the string and persistence fails.

Is there a better way to generate random string i.e. a fail-safe method.

I tried debugging and when I paused the other threads and let them go one by one then it worked fine.

I am currently using the following code to make it more random but i do not like this approach.

```
Random r = new Random();
List<Integer> uniqueNUmbers = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
int x=r.nextInt(9999);
while (uniqueNumbers.contains(x))
x=r.nextInt(9999);
uniqueNumbers.add(x);
} 
String string = String.format("%04d", uniqueNumbers.get(0));

string = uuid + string;
```

But this is like a hacky code. And I dont like this.

Does any one know a fail-proof method to actually geenrate a random string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can synchronize uuid-generation method, and/or you can pregen uuid pool and generate more identificators in one thread when pool starts to deplete.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly think you are barking up the wrong tree.  The real problem here is the (apparently) non-thread-safe way that you are using `UUID.randomUUID`.  (You didn't show us the code for that, so we can't spot the actual issue for you!)  The best solution would be to find and fix the thread safety problem.

Don't try implementing your own random/unique string generator.  Doing that will just create more problems down the track.

For example, your use of `Random` like this would effectively limit you to ~2^48 distinct UUIDs ... because that is the seed length for `Random`; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html.   `ThreadLocalRandom` has the same problem.

Even if you get your implementation correct, you still need to deal with the underlying thread safety issue.  And you have added a bunch of (IMO) unnecessary code to your code base that needs thorough unit testing ... and has to be maintained for the lifetime of your code base.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
int uuid = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example can help someone in the future:

```java
UUID uuid = UuidCreator.getRandomBased();
```

This library uses `java.security.SecureRandom`:

https://github.com/f4b6a3/uuid-creator

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same thing. I was calling `UUID.randomUUID()` in a multi-threaded application. Different threads were getting the same UUID. For me (and I'm guessing you), this was because I was stored uuid in a static variable:

```
  static class UserJourneyThread implements Callable<UserJourneyResult> {

    private static final String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    public UserJourneyResult call() {
    }
  }
```

If `call()` is called once per thread, this should fix the problem:

```
  private static final ThreadLocal<String> uuid =
      ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

In my case, each thread called `call()` multiple times, so I had to move `UUID.randomUUID()` into `call()`.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i have applied all possible solutions. Even the library by [v1ma-8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4408712/v1ma-8) still getting me repeated results. I have figured out that the issue is related to number of active threads .. it's reasonable to get the same id by the same thread...

I have used `server.tomcat.threads.min-spare` option in tomcat to increase the number of threads for testing and it works fine as long as you don't exceed this min number.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).